# grpc timeout in a celery task

Tags: python, celery, grpc

I am trying to connect to a GRPC server in a celery task. I have the following piece of code

```
    timeout = 1
    host = '0.tcp.ngrok.io'
    port = '7145'
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('{0}:{1}'.format(host, port))
    try:
        grpc.channel_ready_future(channel).result(timeout=timeout)
    except grpc.FutureTimeoutError:
        sys.exit(1)
    stub = stub(channel)
```

When I run this snippet through the Python shell, I am able to establish the connection, and execute the GRPC methods. However, when I run this through the Celery task, I get the `grpc.FutureTimeoutError`, and the connection does not get established.

The Celery worker lies on the same machine as the grpc server. I tried using the `socket` library to ping the GRPC server, and that worked (It returned some junk response).

I am using Python 2.7, with `grpcio==1.6.0` installed. The Celery version is 4.1.0. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Are you running the shell and celery on the same machine? Are you sure there is no firewall involved here?

Comment: They are running on the same machine. There should not be a connection issue, because in the Celery task, I tried connecting with the `socket` library. It was able to hit the grpc server (though it did not connect)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe Celery uses fork under the hood, and gRPC 1.6 did not support any forking behavior.

Try updating to gRPC 1.7.

Comment: Took two senior engineers 3 hours to track it down to this.  If only we had searched sooner.